# How can I delete a folder which it can't be done easily?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-xp

There is a folder named Recycler in the directory of my external hard drive and it has a subfolder named `cvx` which I cannot delete it. I used `cmd` to do this. I wanted to change it using `attrib -h -s /d /s`, but it reported `Access Denied -L:\Recycler\cvx`, I also tried to delete it using `del cvx`, but it couldn't be done. Could you help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Right click the CMD icon and select `run as administrator' and in that window you may be able to delete the folder.

Comment: This is not true, if admin dont have Full control permissions.

Comment: I didn't set a password while installing Windows XP, but I cannot run it as an administrator. Could you please help me?

Comment: Then presumably you are in an password-less admin account already.  You can download `Total Commander` which is fully functional shareware File-manager (a startup prompt is all it has) and change the setting to view hidden and system files/folders, and it should be easy to delete it in the GUI.  In Total Commander, F8/Del is the delete key of the item which is under the cursor, or use the mouse.

Comment: The account which I use it to do those things is "Computer Administrator" type(I can see in the "User accounts"), but when I right click the CMD icon to run as administrator, It wanted me to provide the password which I am sure I didn't set up any. How can I activate the administrator account?

Comment: Use the `user accounts` control panel applet and add a password to your account, and remove it again after you have removed the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Access Denied sounds like a permissions issue.

```
takeown /f L:\Recycler /r /d y
icacls L:\Recycler /grant administrators:F /t
rd /s/q "L:\Recycler\cvx"
```

Comment: This is better than Dale answer. :-)

Comment: Could you please give a detailed description? Should I do those things in cmd?

Comment: TTBOMK you will not have icacls in Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to change the access permissions using the dialog in windows explorer

1. Right-click a file or folder > properties
2. Open "security" tab
3. Click edit button
4. Click on current user's name
5. Ensure "full control" "allow" box is checked
6. Click "ok"
7. Click "ok"

Attempts to delete should be made easier by that.